# do something while the key press and release

Tags: vb.net

looks like my old question already left behind

I'm having difficulty looking for a way to do it

I want my application do something when key press. For example, when user press F1 then it will sendkeys F1 as long as F1 still press and when user release F1 it won't sendkeys F1.

I couldn't find a way to make my application keep press F1 before F1 release

here's the code

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor
Imports MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor.WinApi

Public Class Form1

Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "User32" (ByVal vKey As Keys) As Integer
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "User32" Alias "mouse_event" (ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dx As Integer, ByVal dy As Integer, ByVal cButtons As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2 ' left button down
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4 ' left button up

Private WithEvents myKeyboardHookManager As KeyboardHookListener
Dim hookEnabled As Boolean
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    myKeyboardHookManager = New KeyboardHookListener(New GlobalHooker())
    myKeyboardHookManager.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub HookManager_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.F1 To Keys.F9
            SendKeys.Send("{F" + Convert.ToChar(e.KeyValue - 63) + "}")
    End Select
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If hookEnabled Then
        hookEnabled = False
        RemoveHandler myKeyboardHookManager.KeyDown, AddressOf HookManager_KeyDown
    Else
        hookEnabled = True
        AddHandler myKeyboardHookManager.KeyDown, AddressOf HookManager_KeyDown
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

This code work fine but it only press once. What do I want is it keep pressing before I release

thanks for anyhelp

Comment: I can't see how you get anything other than an infinite stream of keyboard events.  It's a really bad idea to send keyboard events from a keyboard hook.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: as explained in your previous post, windows works that way as it is, as long as a key is held down, the app will get messages that key X is pressed. unless there is something you are not telling us, what you need to do is write code to respond to listen to those key events and do whatever it is supposed to do (hopefully something other than generate more keystrokes)

Comment: Id this a console app? Or what?